# How to get Git modified ,removed and new line numbers

Tags: git

I am trying to get the line number for newly added,modified and removed lines from git repo from the previous commit.   I am using the below bash function to get the work done. But I am not able to get path value(it is showing null) and my line numbers are also not exact what I am expecting .please check my output below.

```
diff-lines() {
        local path=
        local line=
        while read; do
            esc=$'\033'
            if [[ $REPLY =~ ---\ (a/)?.* ]]; then
                continue
            elif [[ $REPLY =~ \+\+\+\ (b/)?([^[:blank:]$esc]+).* ]]; then
                path=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
            elif [[ $REPLY =~ @@\ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\ \+([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\ @@.*]]; then
                line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
            elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^($esc\[[0-9;]+m)*([\ +-]) ]]; then
                echo "$path:$line:$REPLY"
                if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != - ]]; then
                    ((line++))
                fi
            fi
        done
    }
```

I am getting below output When I run the script

```
    $ git diff -U0 | diff-lines
    ::+++ b/shipserv/shipserv.cpp
    :1:-
    :1:-// check command-line args
    :1:+// check command-line argsss
    :2:+++ b/shipserv/shipserv_client.cpp
    :3:-// #include <infra/utility/environment/config/PimpConfig.h>
    :3:+// #include <nfra/utility/environment/config/PimpConfig.h>
    :4:+++ b/shipserv/test.text
    :5:-dfssdfsdfsdfsf
    :5:+dfssdfsdfsdfsfZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
    :6:+modified linsde 9898989
    :7:+New line added
```

could anyone  please help me out on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `git log -n 1 --stat`, perhaps? In my repo:

```
commit 0e35181e68f628234c53347c00a75d7af37bb45e
Author: Horst H. von Brand <vonbrand@example.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 17 15:46:32 2013 -0300

    The proper bibliography key is oliveiraXXX..., add latest results

    Signed-off-by: Horst H. von Brand <vonbrand@example.com>

 logica.tex | 16 +++++++++++++---
 url.bib    | 45 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++------------------
 2 files changed, 40 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
```